# Unable to force copy multiple files using single command non-interactively

Tags: solaris, cp, file-copy, prompt, interactive

I wish to force copy a set of files having either the same or different names to a single destination on the same host **with a single command** onn Solaris.

Note: the copy should be forced overrite and non-interactive.

I emptied the destination folder using `rm -rf *` and then fired the copy command as below which does not work.

```
ls -ltrq /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war    
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200209070 Nov 16 15:32 /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war
```

Force copy Gets me an error:

```
[root@ip-10-237-130-101 ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111]# cp -fT /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/Templates/mytemplate1.xls /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/ROOT.war '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war' /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111/    
cp: extra operand '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war'    
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

Another Error while passing input:

```
echo yes | cp /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/Templates/mytemplate1.xls /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/ROOT.war '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war' /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/NOCO_15Jan2024_111/
cp: overwrite '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/NOCO_15Jan2024_111/ROOT.war'? cp: will not overwrite just-created '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/NOCO_15Jan2024_111/ROOT.war' with '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war'
[root@myhost NOCO_15Jan2024_111]# echo $?
1
```

This command Gets me an interactive prompt:

```
[root@ip-10-137-150-101vNOCO_15Jan2024_111]# cp /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/Templates/mytemplate1.xls /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/ROOT.war '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war' /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/NOCO_15Jan2024_111/    
cp: overwrite '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111/ROOT.war'?
```

cp command HELP:

```
[root@ip-10-237-120-101 ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111]# cp --help    
Usage: cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST    
  or:  cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY    
  or:  cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...    
Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.    
     
Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

  -a, --archive                same as -dR --preserve=all    
      --attributes-only        don't copy the file data, just the attributes    
      --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file    
  -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument    
      --copy-contents          copy contents of special files when recursive    
  -d                           same as --no-dereference --preserve=links    
  -f, --force                  if an existing destination file cannot be
                               opened, remove it and try again (this option
                               is ignored when the -n option is also used)
  -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite (overrides a previous -n    
                               option)
  -H                           follow command-line symbolic links in SOURCE
  -l, --link                   hard link files instead of copying
  -L, --dereference            always follow symbolic links in SOURCE
  -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file (overrides
                               a previous -i option)
  -P, --no-dereference         never follow symbolic links in SOURCE
  -p                           same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
      --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]   preserve the specified attributes (default:
                                 mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible
                                 additional attributes: context, links, xattr,
                                 all
  -c                           deprecated, same as --preserve=context
      --no-preserve=ATTR_LIST  don't preserve the specified attributes
      --parents                use full source file name under DIRECTORY
  -R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively
      --reflink[=WHEN]         control clone/CoW copies. See below
      --remove-destination     remove each existing destination file before
                                 attempting to open it (contrast with --force)
      --sparse=WHEN            control creation of sparse files. See below
      --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
                                 argument
  -s, --symbolic-link          make symbolic links instead of copying
  -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
  -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file
  -u, --update                 copy only when the SOURCE file is newer
                                 than the destination file or when the
                                 destination file is missing
  -v, --verbose                explain what is being done
  -x, --one-file-system        stay on this file system
  -Z                           set SELinux security context of destination
                                 file to default type
      --context[=CTX]          like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the
                                 SELinux or SMACK security context to CTX
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
 

By default, sparse SOURCE files are detected by a crude heuristic and the
corresponding DEST file is made sparse as well.  That is the behavior
selected by --sparse=auto.  Specify --sparse=always to create a sparse DEST
file whenever the SOURCE file contains a long enough sequence of zero bytes.

Use --sparse=never to inhibit creation of sparse files.


When --reflink[=always] is specified, perform a lightweight copy, where the
data blocks are copied only when modified.  If this is not possible the copy
fails, or if --reflink=auto is specified, fall back to a standard copy.
Use --reflink=never to ensure a standard copy is performed.

The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:
 

  none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
  numbered, t     make numbered backups
  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  simple, never   always make simple backups

As a special case, cp makes a backup of SOURCE when the force and backup 
options are given and SOURCE and DEST are the same name for an existing,
regular file.
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What is the output from `which cp`?  Do you have `cp` aliased to always use something like `-i`?

Comment: @AndrewHenle no alias.